# Recover deleted Google Public API Key

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-endpoints

I accidentally deleted by Public API Key for Browser applications under my Google Developer Console. I have an iOS and Android app that are using this key. I don't have the source codes for the apps and they are live on the market. Is there a way to restore or recover the deleted keys?

Answer (score 4):

When you delete the key (I just created one to test it) it asks for confirmation with the following message :

```
The key will be deleted immediately and permanently. Once deleted, it can no longer be used to make API requests.
```

This message clearly indicates that there's no possible recovery

Comment: It's very simple to Delete and then confirm and than realize you did it wrong. E.g. someone else was working on the project before you and you didn't realize that there are live users hooked up to this key.

Comment: @SlavaTodavchich oh... THAT kind of accidental :(.... yeah sorry to have sounded condescending :/ that actually sucks for you :(. Removed the condescending part from my answer.  Can't you download your code from the appcfg.py and changing the key?

Comment: Whenever you - or someone else - deleted it accidentaly or not... the message is quite clear: *immediately and permanently*. This should be the accepted answer since it clearly answers your question: *Is there a way to recover the deleted keys?*.

Comment: Not an answer. It's just a comment reaffirming what is already known.

Comment: @harisewak an answer stating "no sorry this can't be done" IS an answer. The fact it's not a solvable problem doesn't mean "no" isn't an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally deleted a (poorly named) Firebase API Key and there is ZERO way of resetting it from the Firebase side of things aside from blowing away your project and starting anew!

Comment: I deleted the 'auto created' SHA number so it would be gone and I could enter it into the non-auto created one (it had 2 for me). Now it says I already have the SHA used by another client for when i try to enter my current key into the non-autocreated one. I thought at the time that I just couldn't use it twice.

Answer (score 3):

They appear to have added this functionality in the long years since this was first asked.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/deleted

[image]